# Скрыть/показать пароль в IE8

Tags: jquery, javascript, internet-explorer, html, css

```
<script>
   jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    $('#show_password').click(function() {
        var attr = $('#LoginForm_password').attr('type');
        if (attr == 'password') {
                 $('#LoginForm_password').attr('type', 'text').focus();
             $('#lock').removeClass('fa-lock').addClass('fa-unlock-alt').attr('title', 'Скрыть пароль');
        } else {
             $('#LoginForm_password').attr('type', 'password').focus();
             $('#lock').removeClass('fa-unlock-alt').addClass('fa-lock').attr('title', 'Показать пароль');
                }
            });
        });
</script>
```

Сей код не пашет в IE8, кто может сказать почему?
Ie8 ругается на библиотеку jQuery на строку с функцией **setAtribute(name, value + '')**
Пишет "Данная команда не поддерживается".

Answer (score 4):

Потому что он и в правду не поддерживает смену type, поэтому нужно клонировать элемент и вставлять его перед оригиналом, скрыв его.